# Twitter tweet button not working

Tags: html, twitter

I am putting the share buttons from the social networks onto my website and have spent some time trying to line them all up nicely and have just about managed it, but for some reason it won't allow me to click on the 'tweet' button anymore.

Can anyone suggest why this may be? When I remove the divs surrounding the 'tweet' button and the 'social network' div it works fine.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
.social-network{
border:1px solid #000;
width:300px;
overflow:visible;
height:20px;
}

.fb{
float:left;
width:73px;
margin-right:12px;
}

.twitter{
float:left;
width:95px;
margin-right:12px;
}

.google{
float:left;
width:60px;
}



<div class="social-network">

    <div class="fb"><fb:like send="false" layout="button_count" width="150" height="80" show_faces="false"></div>

    <div class="twitter"><a class="twitter-share-button" data-text="this is the best website" data-count="horizontal">Tweet</a></div>

    <div class="google"><g:plusone annotation="bubble" size="medium"></g:plusone></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If memory serves, the `<a>` should have a `href="https://twitter.com/share"` attribute. The Twitter javascript file will then automatically find it and replace it with an actual button.

**-edit-**

Looked it up, the `href` attribute isn't actually needed. It is, however, very important that you include Twitter's widgets.js **after** the `<a>`.

Comment: Even with that I'm still having the same problem

Comment: I've tried putting twitter's widget after the <a> tag now but the same problem still persists.

Comment: Do you have an online example?

Comment: here is the page...http://www.westranchhighschool.com/track/West_Ranch_Track/test%20page.html

Comment: Ok, this is funny. It's not the Twitter one that's the problem, it's the facebook button. It overlays the Twitter button. Here, I highlighted the Facebook button for you: http://www.imgdumper.nl/uploads5/4ed3768b0d5dc/4ed3768b0ce08-Screen_Shot_2011-11-28_at_12.54.38_PM.png

Comment: oh ok yea I've just realised I didn't change the width of the actual facebook button when I was changing the width of the container for it. Thanks for all the help